# ROTATION OF A MATRIX BY 90 degree CLOCKWISE

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was solving a question of matrix rotation by 90 degrees. In the problem, I am taking up a list `k` filled with 0s of the exact degree as passed by the user.

I have tried this following code:

```
def rotate(m):
    k=[]
    f=[]
    print(m)
    for i in range(0,len(m)):
        f.append(0)
    for i in range(0,len(m)):
        k.append(f)
    print(k)
    for i in range(0,len(m)):
        for j in range(0,len(m)):
            print("REPLACING POSITION:",i,j )
            t=m[i][j]
            k[j][len(m)-i-1]=t
    return (k)
print(rotate([[1,2],[3,4]]))
```

I expect the output:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
[[0, 0], [0, 0]]
REPLACING POSITION: 0 0
REPLACING POSITION: 0 1
REPLACING POSITION: 1 0
REPLACING POSITION: 1 1
[[3, 1], [4, 2]]
```

I am getting the output:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
[[0, 0], [0, 0]]
REPLACING POSITION: 0 0
REPLACING POSITION: 0 1
REPLACING POSITION: 1 0
REPLACING POSITION: 1 1
[[4, 2], [4, 2]]
```

Why does the last row keep on repeating? Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Your first loop generates the list `f`.
Your next for loop generates the list `k`, which is meant to contain `len(m)` copies of list `f`. The problem is `f` (and most lists) are just pointers. So list `k` is actually a list of pointers to the *same* list `f`.

Thus all the modifications you make to elements of f in k are made to the same list.

One solution is to use a *copy* of list `f` when generating list `k` by using the slice operator:

```
    for i in range(0,len(m)):
        k.append(f[:])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use f.copy() to get deep copy of the list.

```
    def rotate(m):
    k=[]
    f=[]
    print(m)
    for _ in range(0,len(m)):
        f.append(0)
    for _ in range(0,len(m)):
        k.append(f.copy())
    for i in range(0,len(m)):
        for j in range(0,len(m)):
            print("REPLACING POSITION:",i,j )
            t=m[i][j]
            k[j][len(m)-i-1]=t

            print(j,len(m)-i-1)           
    return k


print(rotate([[1,2],[3,4]]))
```